# Is Custom Building Products sanded ceramic tile caulk paintable?

Tags: paint, caulk

I have a tube of Custom Building Products' Sanded Ceramic Tile Caulk, and it says nothing about paintability on the tube itself. It is "siliconized" caulk per the tube.

On the [online product sheet](https://www.custombuildingproducts.com/TDS/TDS-179.pdf), the technical data section says "Paintable | >Yes", and I don't know if that means "Yes, it is paintable" or "it is **less than** paintable":

[image]

(I have also left a message on their help line and will update here if I get an answer).

Comment: It says paintable, but do not know why it is listed as greater than yes, maybe a typo, since it should be a simple yes or no answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a call back from their help line on Monday: ***this caulk is not paintable* and will repel paint**. I have no idea why they wrote it like that on their spec sheet, I guess "less than yes" is **no** in Custom Solutions caulk language.